# PHP & MySQL and Leaflet API

Tags: php, mysql, leaflet, geojson

I hit a bit of a wall here regarding using PHP & MySQL with Leaflet API. I started with PHP & MYSQL several months ago and I'm kind a newbie in that field but I'm willing to learn so please give me few pointers regarding my problem.

Question is kind a similar to that one:
[Creating a GeoJson in php from MySql to use with MapBox javascript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775627/creating-a-geojson-in-php-from-mysql-to-use-with-mapbox-javascript-api)

So, I'm trying to get markers from a MySQL table using PHP and render it using Leaflet API

First, I created MySQL Table with some data:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.4.6
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Jan 17, 2016 at 08:36 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.24
-- PHP Version: 5.6.8

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `web_gis`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `web_gis` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
USE `web_gis`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `baza`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `baza`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `baza` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `operator` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lokacija` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `x` float NOT NULL,
  `y` float NOT NULL,
  `prijavljen` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `baza`
--

INSERT INTO `baza` (`id`, `operator`, `lokacija`, `x`, `y`, `prijavljen`) VALUES
(1, 'Tele 2', 'OiV stup Hum na Sutli', 46.2135, 15.672, '2016-01-14'),
(2, 'T-Mobile HR', 'OiV stup Straža', 46.2179, 15.6999, '2016-01-03'),
(3, 'T-Mobile HR', 'Lupinjak', 46.2016, 15.7412, '2016-01-23'),
(4, 'T-Mobile HR', 'Klenovec Humski 89\\1', 46.2169, 15.7268, '2016-01-01');
--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--
--
-- Indexes for table `baza`
--
ALTER TABLE `baza`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `baza`
--
ALTER TABLE `baza`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Next, here is my PHP (*bazneStanice_geojson.php*) code which I copied from this site and adjusted a little (changed the name of base to be more precise):

https://github.com/bmcbride/PHP-Database-GeoJSON/blob/master/simple_points/mysql_points_geojson.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Title:   SQLite to GeoJSON (Requires https://github.com/phayes/geoPHP)
 * Notes:   Query a SQLite table or view (with a WKB GEOMETRY field) and return the results in GeoJSON format, suitable for use in OpenLayers, Leaflet, etc. Use QGIS to OGR to convert your GIS data to SQLite.
 * Author:  Bryan R. McBride, GISP
 * Contact: bryanmcbride.com
 * GitHub:  https://github.com/bmcbride/PHP-Database-GeoJSON
 */


# Connect to SQLite database
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web_gis','neven','gis');

# Build SQL SELECT statement and return the geometry as a GeoJSON element
$sql = 'SELECT *, x AS x, y AS y FROM baza';


# Try query or error
$rs = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$rs) {
    echo 'An SQL error occured.\n';
    exit;
}

# Build GeoJSON feature collection array
$geojson = array(
   'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
   'features'  => array()
);

# Loop through rows to build feature arrays
while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $properties = $row;
    # Remove x and y fields from properties (optional)
    unset($properties['x']);
    unset($properties['y']);
    $feature = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',
        'geometry' => array(
            'type' => 'Point',
            'coordinates' => array(
                $row['x'],
                $row['y']
            )
        ),
        'properties' => $properties
    );
    # Add feature arrays to feature collection array
    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($geojson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$conn = NULL;
// print_r($geojson);
?>
```

And here is script block of code. (*skripta_mysql.js*) I must point out that I successfully rendered map and the only thing that I'm missing are the points/markers from MySQL table.

```
var karta = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6IjZjNmRjNzk3ZmE2MTcwOTEwMGY0MzU3YjUzOWFmNWZhIn0.Y8bhBaUMqFiPrDRW9hieoQ', {
maxZoom: 18,
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
'<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
id: 'mapbox.streets'
});

bazne_stanice = new L.geoJson(null, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {

    });
},
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
if (feature.properties) {
    var content = '<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;" cellpadding="2">' +
    '<tr>' + '<th>ID</th>' + '<td>' + feature.properties.operator + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' + '<th>Name</th>' + '<td>' + feature.properties.lokacija + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' + '<th>Address</th>' + '<td>' + feature.properties.y + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' + '<th>Town</th>' + '<td>' + feature.properties.prijavljen + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
    '<table>';
layer.bindPopup(content);}}
});

$.getJSON("bazneStanice_geojson.php", function (data) {
        bazne_stanice.addData(data);
    });

var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [46.15796, 15.75336],
        zoom: 9,
        layers: [karta, bazne_stanice]
    });

var baseLayers = {
        "Podloga": karta
    };

    var overlays = {
        "Bazne stanice": bazne_stanice
    };

    L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

When I print variable $geojson; from php code I get array like this

```
Array
(
    [type] => FeatureCollection
    [features] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Feature
                    [geometry] => Array
                        (
                            [type] => Point
                            [coordinates] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 46.2135
                                    [1] => 15.672
                                )

                        )

                    [properties] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [operator] => Tele 2
                            [lokacija] => OiV stup Hum na Sutli
                            [prijavljen] => 2016-01-14
                        )

                )....
```

To be fair I'm a bit confused. I really don't know what am I missing, followed everthing step by step but still without any luck rendering markers. Is it problem in `$geojson` variable?

Should I be getting combined coordinates in [0]row? 
Something like this?

```
 [coordinates] => Array
(
 [0] => 46.2135, 15.672
)
```

============================

UPDATE:

When I try to echo

```
echo json_encode($geojson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

I didn't get any results 
and I should be getting something like this if I'm not mistaken

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Operator": "T-Mobile HR", "Lokacija": "Poljana Sutlanska 8, Zagorska Sela", "Prijavljen": "21.12.2010.", "Odjavljeno": null }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 431501.48819855711, 5110280.408429144 ] } }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found solution to my problem. Problem was in symbols (č,ž,š,ć,đ..) and if any given attribute had one of the symbols this code would not work:

```
echo json_encode($geojson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

To prevent breaking of code I had to put UTF-8 on PDO connection to check if database string is UTF-8.

Instead of this:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web_gis','neven','gis');
```

So, I inserted something like this:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web_gis;charset=utf8','neven','gis',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
```

and it worked like a charm.

Hope it helps!