# PHP formatting for GeoJSON

Tags: php, arrays, geojson

Trying to use PHP to format data for the geometry part of GeoJSON (Polygon)

```
$sql = "SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(`geom`) as Geo FROM `usa` WHERE 1";
```

Returns records that look like:

```
{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[-101.4073933...
```

My code so far, I tried formatting the geometry block 3 different ways, all failed.:

```
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$msg [] = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',

        'geometry' => 
            $res['Geo'],
         /// ERROR  "geometry" member should be object, but is an String instead
        //"geometry":"{\"type\": \"Polygon\", \"coordinates\": [[[-104.05361517875079, 41.698


        'geometry' => array(
            $res['Geo'],
        ),   ///ERROR "geometry" member should be object, but is an Array instead
        //"geometry":["{\"type\": \"Polygon\", \"coordinates\": [[[-104.05361517875079, 41.6


        'geometry' => array(
            'type' => $res['Geo'].['type'],
            'coordinates' => $res['Geo'].['coordinates'],
        ),  
        //"geometry":{"type":"{\"type\": \"Polygon\", \"coordinates\": [[[[-122.4020155875262, 48.22521
```

It should end up looking something like this:

```
"geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[  -73.3450469
```

Comment: Try looking at the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775627/creating-a-geojson-in-php-from-mysql-to-use-with-mapbox-javascript-api especially that github api posted there

Comment: If you look closely `geomatry` is a string, not an object. It's double encoded. You can notice that because of `\"` before `type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ST_AsGeoJSON` returns, as the name suggests, JSON. That means `$res['Geo']` is a string, a *JSON* string, representing a GeoJSON object. If you put that string into a PHP array which you later `json_encode`, you're producing the JSON encoding of a string. What you want instead is an array or object, which you can then `json_encode` and which will be an object in JSON, not a string.

So, JSON-decode the value you get from the database to get a PHP object:

```
$msg[] = array(
    'type' => 'Feature',
    'geometry' => json_decode($res['Geo']),
    ...
);
```

When JSON-encoding `$msg` later, it'll look like:

```
"geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": ...}
```