# PDOStatement to Geojson

Tags: php, json, geojson

In order to use it in [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/), i need to convert my data queried from **Mysql** with **PDO** to **geojson** format.

I find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770273/pdostatement-to-json) a solution to do that for **json** with `json_encode()`, but i can't find an analogical `geojson_encode()` function or algorithme with php.

so is there a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Solved My problem by reading [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775627/creating-a-geojson-in-php-from-mysql-to-use-with-mapbox-javascript-api)

to have your queried data from Mysql converted to geojson , just try this code :

```
$geojson = array(
    'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
   'features'  => array()
);

$reponses=$bdd->query('SELECT * FROM `nyc_taxi_data_2014` LIMIT 0,30 ');

    while ($data=$reponses->fetch())
    {
        $marker = array(
            'type' => 'Feature',
            'features' => array(
                'type' => 'Feature',
                'properties' => array(
                    'pickup_time' => "".$data['pickup_datetime']

                    ),
                "geometry" => array(
                    'type' => 'Point',
                    'coordinates' => array( 
                                    $data['pickup_longitude'],
                                    $data['pickup_latitude']
                    )
                )
            )
          );

    array_push($geojson['features'], $marker['features']);
    }

echo json_encode($geojson);
```

Comment: the coordinates end up with double quotes. not valid geojson. 
json_decode($row['lng']),
json_decode($row['lat'])